# CodeIgniter, Jquery - append dropdown menu in form

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, append

Hi I'd like some help please. I have created a form in CodeIgniter in which I want to save the name of a movie and the actors who play in. My code looks like this:

```
<?php echo form_open().PHP_EOL; ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title *</label>
        <?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title', html_escape($movie->title)), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
        <?php echo form_error('title'); ?>
    </div>

    <h4>Cast</h4>
    <button type="button" id="add_actor" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Actor</button>
    <hr>
    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="cast"></ul>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_submit('save', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"').PHP_EOL; ?>
    </div>

<?php echo form_close().PHP_EOL; ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var output = '<li style="margin-bottom:5px;">\
                <div class="row">\
                    <div class="col-md-6">\
                        <?php echo form_dropdown("actors", $actors, null, "class=\"form-control\""); ?>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-md-6">\
                        <input type="text" name="character[]" class="form-control"\ placeholder="Character" />\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </li>';

    $('#add_actor').click(function() {
        $('#cast').append(output);
    });
});
```

On firebug I get this as output:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var output = '<li style="margin-bottom:5px;">;\
                    <div class="row">;\
                        <div class="col-md-6">;\
                            <select name="actors" class="form-control">
<option value="5">Keira Knightley</option>
<option value="7">Matthew Goode</option>
<option value="6">Benedict Cumberbatch</option>
<option value="2">Christian Bale</option>
<option value="10">Jude Law</option>
<option value="4">Daniel Craig</option>
<option value="3">Brad Pitt</option>
<option value="1">Johnny Depp</option>
<option value="9">Sean Bean</option>
<option value="8">Pierce Brosnan</option>
<option value="11">Ed Harris</option>
<option value="12">Judi Dench</option>
</select>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-md-6">\
                           <input type="text" name="character[]" class="form-control"\ placeholder="Character" />\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </li>';

        $('#add_actor').click(function() {
            $('#cast').append(output);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I probably guess that the error is caused because the form_dropdown() doesn't have the \ at the end of the line.

So what I'm trying to do basicly is when I click the "Add Actor" button the jquery will append a row in my form where it should have a dropdown menu for choosing the actor, and next to this dropdown an input field for typing the actor's character in the movie. When I click the "Add Actor" button again I will to the same process again to enter the next actor in the movie, etc etc.

However the code in the script tag doesn't work as I expected, In fact jquery complains for syntax error. I 'm checking my code and try some changes but no effect.

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in your console as you have ill formatted string literal.

Add `\` at the end of each line for the `output`

```
var output = '<li style="margin-bottom:5px;">\
                    <div class="row">\
                        <div class="col-md-6">\
                            <?php echo form_dropdown("actors", $actors); ?>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-md-6">\
                            <input type="text" name="character[]" class="form-control"\ placeholder="Character" />\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </li>';
```

You can't begin a new line at the middle of a string literal without telling the compiler that the string is continued in the next line, so in your case you can use the `\` operator as given above to indicate that.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8tnh49e/)

Comment: No, still remains the problem. I get SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Comment: can you update [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8tnh49e/1/) to recreate the issue

Comment: are you sure the latest code is used by the browser, ie there is no caching involved

Comment: and check whether the error is coming from any other part of the code

Comment: No it doesn't seems to involve cache.. this line <?php echo form_dropdown("actors", $actors); ?> is a codeingter build-in function, it takes as 1st param the name of the drodown and the array of elements.. I don't belive there's a problem with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71232/discussion-between-lykos-and-arun-p-johny).

Comment: How can I fetch all the selected values from the dropdowns and the input fields in case I want to do an UPDATE ???